# installing docker cloud cli on windows

Tags: docker, docker-cloud

I am new to docker and setting up the environment in my windows 7 laptop to begin learning. I installed docker through docker toolbox. To install docker cloud cli, I followed the official documentation

https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/installing-cli/#install

I opened the quick start terminal and executed :

```
       docker run dockercloud/cli -h
```

[image]

but while verifying the cloud version I am getting error 'bash: docker-cloud: command not found'.

Then I tried executing with pip command but didnt work.

[image]

I have below tools installed :

```
     Python 2.7.13
     Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be
     docker-machine version 0.11.0, build 5b27455
```

and I have also verified that the docker engine is in running status.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The docker-cloud commands is not installed as part of the Docker Toolbox installation.

The first command that you run is running a docker container that does run the Docker Cloud CLI. Running this container also is not a way to install the docker-cloud command directly to your windows host. You can always invoke the same 'docker run dockercloud/cli' command to run the CLI containerized.

Similarly, the pip command is not installed as part of the Docker Toolbox installation. pip is something I would expect to be installed if you install Python on your windows system.

If you take a look at: https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/installing-cli/#install, the section for installing docker-cloud on windows does include this piece of advice:

> If you do not have Python or `pip` installed, you can either [install Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Download) or use this [standalone pip installer](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py). You do not need Python for our purposes, just `pip`.

You did mention that you have python installed, but you are still getting "command not found" when you try to run pip. That could simply be a problem with the `$PATH` in the quickstart terminal. I would recommend trying the pip command from a powershell window rather than the quickstart terminal. If you do have the pip command somewhere on your system, make sure that the location it is installed to does appear in your `$PATH` in the bash inside the quickstart terminal.

Once you have pip installed, and in your `$PATH`, you should be able to run the `pip install docker-cloud` command.

It would also be a good idea to make sure that the directory holding the installed docker-cloud binary will also appear in your `$PATH` inside the quickstart terminal.

Comment: I appreciated your response. However, in the official documentation(ie. the link I mentioned in the problem description,) it was asked to check the cloud version after 'run dockercloud.. ' command. That point is not clear to me.

Comment: The `docker run dockercloud/cli` appears under the section "RUN THE CLI IN A DOCKER CONTAINER". That is a valid way to run the cli, but it will not somehow install the windows binary onto your windows system if you want to run the cli inside a linux container.